# Android notification becomes ongoing with certain flags

Tags: java, android, notifications, vibration

Ok,

Possibly another bizare undocumented quirk of android, but I'm finding something quite odd when adding flags to my notification...

If I do this:

```
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.status_icon, "[Ticker Text]",System.currentTimeMillis());

  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, CarparkScreen.class), 0);

  notification.setLatestEventInfo(AlertService.this,"[Title]", "[Detail]", intent);

  mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION_BREACH, notification);
```

Then the notification appears as a one off, clicking cancels is and you can clear it in the normal way.

If however I add these flags

```
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.status_icon, "[Ticker Text]",System.currentTimeMillis());

  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, CarparkScreen.class), 0);

  notification.setLatestEventInfo(AlertService.this,"[Title]", "[Detail]", intent);

  notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

  mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION_BREACH, notification);
```

It creates an *ongoing* notification, despite there being no *ongoing* flag!!

I think its actually the DEFAULT_VIRBATE flag which is causing this, which at first I though was because I didn't have vibrate permissions, but I've added that now but it still causes the notification to be ongoing.

Urgh!!!!

Can anyone else re-create this? Seems such an obvious use case to be a bug or quirk.

I am actually using an ongoing notification at the same time as trying to create a non-ongoing notification above, but this really shouldn't cause this as I'm using new instances of everything apart from the NotificationManager. The ID in the above code is also different to the ongoing notification.

Any ideas muchly appreciated! :)

Andy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It creates an ongoing notification, despite there being no ongoing flag!!

The `flags` field gets `FLAG_` constants. The `defaults` field get `DEFAULT_` constants. You are putting `DEFAULT_` constants in the `flags` field. Try changing your code to use the `defaults` field.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot! Feel kinda silly now! lol. Think there are a few examples around the internets which I must have copied this mistake from! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Andy: I'm not sure why Android doesn't use enums for stuff like this, as (I think) they would catch this stuff at compile time.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm sure you've seen by now, but they added a blub about how enums use more memory in their since-added [memory usage document](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead).

Comment: @DavidCowden: If an `Enum` instance requires eight bytes instead of four, I fail to see the concern. That'd be *way* down my list of priorities of memory issues to worry about. Next, they'll say we should cap strings to be no longer than 11 characters. Thanks for pointing that out, though!